# printf changing its value after it should have already been printed

Tags: c, printf

So I have this code here, that (for now) just turns a base1 number in to a base 10 number

```
/**
 * This function is supposed to convert 'number' from base1 to a number in base2.
 * It isn't fully implemented yet, and I've only converted base1 to a base 10 number.
 */
void base1_base2(int base1, int base2, int number) {

    int num, place = 0;
    int rem = number;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_digits(number); i++) {

        int mod = rem % 10;
        rem = floor(rem / 10);

        int powerResult = pow(base1, place++);
        num = num + mod * powerResult;  
    }

    int base10_num = num;

    printf("The number %i(base%i) in base 10 is: %i\n", number, base1, base10_num);
}
```

And this calculates the correct base10 number, i.e. the function call 
base1_convert(2, 5, 100) would return 4, as expected:

`The number 100(base2) in base 10 is: 4`

The problem arises when I add this code directly beneath the last printf in that function:

```
int base2_num = 0;
printf("The number %i(base%i) is: %d\n", number, base1, base2_num);
```

If the above code is added, it completely changes the result of the first printf, making it return:

```
The number 100(base2) in base 10 is: 4196784.
The number 100(base2) is: 0
```

I can not for the life of me figure out why this is happening. I'm guessing it has to do with some pointers, but I haven't really used any, and I have no idea why adding a seemingly independent variable `int base2_num = 0;` would change all of that.

Here is the complete modified code after the above lines are added.

```
void base1_base2(int base1, int base2, int number) {

    int num, place = 0;
    int rem = number;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_digits(number); i++) {

        int mod = rem % 10;
        rem = floor(rem / 10);

        int powerResult = pow(base1, place++);
        num = num + mod * powerResult;  
    }

    int base10_num = num;

    printf("The number %i(base%i) in base 10 is: %i\n", number, base1, base10_num);

    int base2_num = 0;
    printf("The number %i(base%i) is: %d\n", number, base1, base2_num);

    return;
}
```

Edit: And here is the only other function I used, num_digits. It returns the number of digits in an integer.

```
int num_digits(int integer) {

    char int_string[100];
    int str_length;
    sprintf(int_string, "%i", integer);
    str_length = strlen(int_string);

    return str_length;
}
```

And here is where I call the function:

```
int main() {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    base1_base2(2, 5, 100);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what's a `base1` number?

Comment: @gokcehan:  "chicken scratches" as we used to call them:  the number of digits is the value.

Comment: @gokcehan In my example I converted from 100 in base 2 to a number in base 10, so `base1` would be 2, and `number` would be 100. The expected result would be 4.

Comment: Makes no sense. Also it can't be you add that line because then the output would have to be in 2 lines and not one. Can you please post the second (modified) `base1_convert()`

Comment: THe only reason it's not on two lines is because I couldn't get it formatted correctly when posting it here. I'll post the modified version in an edit now.

Comment: I just realized something I changed to make things simpler may have had an effect. I'm changing it back.

Comment: @Michael: It is considered bad manner to *not* provide an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/) (simple, self-contained, compilable example). To even reproduce your problem, I'd have to code a `main()` that feeds it numbers, which is the point at which I lost interest in helping you.

Comment: In the loop, if `rem` is in `base1`, it seems very strange to treat it as a decimal number when grabbing digits (with `% 10` and so on).

Comment: @DevSolar In the future, how should I have posted my code? Should I have posted my main function as well?

Comment: @Michael: Follow the link in my comment. It explains it at length. Bullet points: Provide a `main()`. Include all necessary headers (stdio, match, string in this case). It should be possible to copy, paste, compile your example and immediately get the same result as you. (MWE, minimal workable example, is another acronym for this.)

Comment: @DevSolar Thanks, missed the link the first time I read it. This is my first time writing in C, and as you can tell I'm a little uninformed. I won't make the same mistake again!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just care to write :

```
int num = 0, place = 0;
```

And you will be surely done.

That's why I recommend declaring one variable by line.

Comment: It looks like we have a winner. Do you have any idea why adding `int base2_num = 0;` seemed to cause this problem to actually pop up? It was fine before adding that line.

Comment: Because changing the ouput binary lead to a change in position in memory when executing it, so you had less luck with `num` being zero randomly.

Comment: @Michael: A good habit to get into is to only declare one variable per line. Avoids several problems.

Comment: And avoid mixing declarations and statements too.

Answer (score 2):

As you, I don't see what is going on here.

If this was 1990, I'd say that you use 32bit int values and `printf()` expects 16bit ints but that can't be true in this case: If there was a width mismatch, then all the other numbers would be wrong, too. So it would print either

```
The number 0(base100)
```

or

```
The number 100(base0)
```

depending on the endianess of your platform.

Since the problem isn't in your code, it must be elsewhere. Suggestions:

1. Try to get rid of `num_digits()`. See the comments below.
2. Add more `printf()`s to see how all the values change
3. Run the code in a debugger
4. Turn off all optimization flags of your compiler. Maybe one of the triggers a bug.
5. Enable all the warning flags that your compiler supports.

Some comments:

1. `num_digits(number)` is a pretty expensive function; don't call it in a loop (i.e. N times). Cache the result in a local variable instead. Or simply stop when `rem` is 0 (i.e. replace the `for` loop with `while(0 != rem)`).
2. The name `base1` is bad. Use `inputBase` instead because that communicates intent.
3. There is no need to use `floor()`; integer division always rounds down.

Comment: 1: Thanks you're definitely right. I changed that.
2: Right again, but this is for a school assignment and they used base1, which is why I initially did. Still a great idea, so I changed that as well.
3: And right for a third time, thanks.